# sending a SOAP message via HTTP in java

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have the following code:

```
  String xmldata = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>" + 
        "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" " + 
          "xmlns:wsdl=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/\" " + 
          "xmlns:ns1=\"http://org.apache.axis2/xsd\"  " + 
          "xmlns:ns=\"http://tfc\" " +
          "xmlns:wsaw=\"http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl\" " +
          "xmlns:http=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/\"  " +
          "xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"" +
          "xmlns:mime=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/\"  " +
          "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/\"  " +
          "xmlns:soap12=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/\"  " +
          "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"  " +
          "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" > " +
          "<SOAP-ENV:Body>" +
              "<ns:CalFare xmlns:ns=\"http://tfc\">" +
              "<ns:nonairport>1</ns:nonairport>" +
              "<ns:distance>20</ns:distance>" +
              "</ns:CalFare>" +
          "</SOAP-ENV:Body>" +
          "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

          //Create socket
          String hostname = "128.196.239.112";
          int port = 8080;
          InetAddress  addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
          Socket sock = new Socket(addr, port);

          //Send header
          String path = "/LocatorzTaxiFare/services/Calculator.CalculatorHttpSoap11Endpoint/";
          BufferedWriter  wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));
          // You can use "UTF8" for compatibility with the Microsoft virtual machine.
          wr.write("POST " + path + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
          wr.write("Host: 128.196.239.112\r\n");
          wr.write("Content-Length: " + xmldata.length() + "\r\n");
          wr.write("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n");
          wr.write("\r\n");

          //Send data
          wr.write(xmldata);
          wr.flush();

          // Response
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
          String line;
          while((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now it's giving me an internal server error with the following response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:Action>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</wsa:Action></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode></faultcode><faultstring>com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'x' (code 120) excepted space, or '>' or "/>"&#xd;
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,390]</faultstring><detail /></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here's a [link](http://128.196.239.112:8080/LocatorzTaxiFare/services/Calculator?wsdl) to the WSDL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a glance, it looks like the XML that you're sending it is invalid. The XML processor found an 'x' when it was looking for a space, a '>' or a '/>'. So, fix your payload.

Yup...here it is:

```
 "xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"" +
 "xmlns:mime=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/\"  " +
```

That first line is wrong, you need to add the trailing space (like in the second line).

Mind, it helps to read the error messages. This is exactly what it said was wrong. No real magic here.